# Starting project with 100s of data conversions into a SQL database. What is the correct way?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dts, data-conversion

We will have about 200 files (csv, excel, PDF, screen scrape) that all need to go into a SQL db. So there will be a unique procedure for most data sources

Only 2 ideas we have so far are:

1. Write code to programmatically load each data source in as needed and write code to insert as needed (this is the simple way but maybe most time consuming)
2. Write an XML map for each file that maps column from the source to columns/tables of the destination SQL DB.. But then writing code to interpret this custom XML mapping file could get complex?

Any other tools or methods we should consider?  I though maybe SSIS could help somehow ? This seems to be the type of project BizTalk was made for right? But that is too expensive..

Comment: The insertion code should be the same for all data types, so you only need to parse each type to a common structure. Also note that Excel files can be exported to CSV, and may be true for some of your other data types as well.

Comment: Yes. That was an idea as well. but the destination for all the data goes different places in different ways so its not like I have many data sources with just one data destination

Comment: Then you need a parser for each data input type, and a writer for each output type, with the possibility that some iput types can auto-conver themselves.

Comment: I'm not saying this applies to you, but in my experience people often invest weeks in trying to find a 'generic' way to import their data when they could have spent a lot less time just doing the work of writing one transformation script for each data source. Especially when you have very heterogeneous data, it's often not clear at first if a generic solution is even possible so it's usually best to 'just do it' with your preferred language and tools and having done that you will be in a much better position to identify ways to refactor common transformations and tasks.

Comment: im leaning toward doing it the not very elegant way of coding it.. after I do a couple there with be a lot of cut and pasting and not code to be proud to show off but it will be done vs. trying to create some solution that take a lot of time and ends up being fragile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Pondlife mentioned, in real world solutions, programmatic solutions usually become more and more difficult to maintain and support as the full complexity of the requirements is uncovered.  This is often not obvious up front.

I would choose a good ETL tool - SSIS is usually the best choice at present on the balance of typical criteria. Then you need to budget an amount of man-days to work through each input.  Probably the quickest you will achieve is 0.5 man-days per file (including design, build and unit testing) for a very simple input.

You can save some time by copying your first package as a starting point for the others.

With "raw" inputs like this I typically start each package by just loading the data unaltered into a Staging table.  At this point I load every column as unicode text.  Then subsequent Data Flows or packages can pick that data up and deliver it.  This approach really speeds debugging, testing and auditing - once you trust your file load you can query the Staging table with SQL.

BTW the SSIS package is in fact an XML document that describes the input, transformation and output requirements - similar to your point 2.

Comment: What issues are there with SSIS mixing it with code?  Is it as simple as create a package, create parameters that the code sends to the package and move the code and the DLLs needed to run the package to the server. . is that basically it ?

Comment: id like to do 2 in 1.. I mean for example.. some sources are .xls so have SSIS convert that into a table as well as move it into the final tables... I need to learn more about SSIS.. I Had some issues reading .xls files on a 64-bit system

Comment: @punkouter 1st comment: there is a deployment wizard to go through but it's pretty straight-forward. SQL 2012 is a huge improvement in this area.

Comment: @punkouter 2nd comment: a single SSIS package can include multiple tasks with complex constraints (visual designer). xls files on 64-bit is awkward but can be done with the Access Database Engine drivers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no correct way universally. It only matters what's easier for your specific situation. I'd go with the path of least resistance here. This means if some files are easier to map with xml (probably csv, excel and such) I'd use xml mapping for those. For others where xml mapping doesnt work I'd go with something else.

The reality is that some methods work better with one type of data sources and other methods work better with other type.

Comment: I was thinking for the really straight forward ones I could use a XML mapping file.. but then again these files are only run once a year and is it really that big of a deal to put the parameters in code rather than XML..... I would love to use SSIS for something so beyond doing it all in code ill dig into what SSIS has to over..

Comment: Well.... if it's once per year then just go with what's easier for you :). It doesn't matter much if it's not something you execute more frequently.... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Perl.  Just hack at each file type to produce a delimited file suitable to bcp load into the database.  Often as not you can use regular expressions in Perl to grab stuff even out of XML files, but if you know XML and the inputs really are well formed, Perl has lots of parsers to turn proper XML into proper data.  ;-)

Perl on Windows will automate Excel through Ole, too.  Been there, done that, works about as well as can be expected.  Save the file as text. Maybe iterate over it to fix it up.  Repeat as necessary.

I don't agree that this sort of thing isn't amenable to programming, as someone else suggested.  It's not perfectable, but errors can be reduced asymptotically, which isn't the case with a manual process.

Keep your scripts, inputs, and outputs all in different directories.  That way you can use Perl (or whatever) to count the files and verify the transformations.  If you're careful with your names and extensions, it will be easy to see what remains to be done.  Make your scripts to everything, soup to nuts, including loading the database, so that you can re-run it whenever you want idempotently.  Very satisfying after you notice a problem in the data in the database that can only be fixed by tweaking the parser.

Happy hacking.